# LOG4j - ways to configure it

Tags: java, log4j

I'd like to configure `log4j` in a huge distributed system. There are a lot of JVMs and processes and (as I am only a student) I am new to such a situation. I use `JMS Appender`, so I need two files: `log4j.properties`, `jndi.properties`.

I've tried some ways:

1. Put these files into `src` folder
2. or into `src/java`
3. add jvm argument `-Dlog4j.configuration=C:\...\log4j.properties`

I don't want to set it in code using `PropertyConfigurator.configure("path")`, because I'd like to not change source code at all.

Are there any other ways to configure `log4j`? Or maybe I am missing something? I still get a messages

```
No appenders could be found for logger (some.package.SomeClass). 
Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Comment: May be this will help you [configuring Log4j using XML and properties file.](http://www.javabeat.net/2008/07/baisc-steps-to-configure-log4j-using-xml-and-properties-file/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you have the following ways to configure Log4J:

1. Via your code
2. properties file (as you're trying to use)
3. Xml File

What you're asking to me related to specific configuration of JMS appender  and its not about 'general way of how to configure log4j'

Here is an example of how to configure it with ActiveMQ 
For other JMS implementations in your property file the keys will be probably the same but the values will be different

[Example - using JMS appender with ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j-jms-appender-with-activemq.html)

Comment: I used this tutorial and JMS Appender successfully, but in a small program. Now I'd like to configure it in a huge system, so my question is about 'general way of how to configure log4j' in distributed systems.

Comment: I see, basically log4j configuration exists per JVM. So you have to ensure your log4j configuration can work with all JVM processes you have in your system. If you use application servers the things can become even more complicated, so I would start with mapping all your processes and understanding which of them use Log4j and where in the  code they get configured. Without this understanding I'm afraid you won't be able to configure this properly.